# How do I set up an rc.d script to start Plex Media Server in FreeBSD?

Tags: sh, freebsd, plex

My LG TV stop working with my older version of Plex 1.3 so I was forced to update to Plex 1.13

I'm running my version of Plex on Nas4Free 0.9 in a jail.

I was able to download and it runs but will not auto start. For some reason the plexmediaserver script in /etc/local/rc.d fails.

Has anyone else out there had a similar issue. I only know a little shell scripting other wise I would try and fix it myself.

This is the current script which came with the older version of Plex

```
#!/bin/sh
# Created by: KalleDK <plexmaintainer@k-moeller.dk>
#
# $FreeBSD: head/multimedia/plexmediaserver/files/plexmediaserver.in 409168 2016-02-19 11:41:13Z feld $
#
# PROVIDE: plexmediaserver
# REQUIRE: LOGIN
# KEYWORD: shutdown
#
# Add the following lines to /etc/rc.conf to enable the Plex Media Server:
#
# plexmediaserver_enable="YES"
#
# plexmediaserver_support_path="/usr/local/plexdata" # Plex data: logs, media metadata, settings, etc
#
# plexmediaserver_tmp="/var/tmp/plex" # configure tmp directory used for the transcoding process if desired
#
# plexmediaserver_maxplugins="6" # Maximum number of background plugin procs. May have to raise in rare cases.
#

. /etc/rc.subr

name=plexmediaserver
rcvar=plexmediaserver_enable
load_rc_config $name

: ${plexmediaserver_enable:=NO}
: ${plexmediaserver_support_path="/usr/local/plexdata"}
: ${plexmediaserver_user="plex"}
: ${plexmediaserver_group="plex"}
: ${plexmediaserver_maxplugins=6}

command=/usr/sbin/daemon
procname="/usr/local/share/plexmediaserver/Plex_Media_Server"
command_args="-f ${procname}"
pidfile=/var/run/plex/plex.pid
start_precmd=plex_precmd
stop_precmd=plex_stop_precmd
stop_postcmd=plex_stop_postcmd

plex_precmd()
{
    export SUPPORT_PATH="${plexmediaserver_support_path}"
    export HOME="${plexmediaserver_support_path}/Plex Media Server"
    export PYTHONHOME="/usr/local/share/plexmediaserver/Resources/Python"
    export SCRIPTPATH="/usr/local/share/plexmediaserver"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/compat:${SCRIPTPATH}"
    export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_HOME="${SCRIPTPATH}"
    export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_MAX_PLUGIN_PROCS=${plexmediaserver_maxplugins}
    export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR=${plexmediaserver_support_path}
    export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_PIDFILE=${pidfile}
    export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_LOG_DIR="${plexmediaserver_support_path}/Plex Media Server/Logs"
    export PATH="${SCRIPTPATH}/Resources/Python/bin:${PATH}"
    export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
    export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
    ulimit -s 3000

    if [ ! -d ${pidfile%/*} ]; then
        echo "Option 1"
        install -d -o ${plexmediaserver_user} ${pidfile%/*};
    fi

    if [ ! -d "${plexmediaserver_support_path}/Plex Media Server" ]; then
        echo "Option 2"
        install -d -g ${plexmediaserver_group} -o ${plexmediaserver_user} "${plexmediaserver_support_path}/Plex Media Server";
    fi

    if [ ${plexmediaserver_tmp} ]; then
        "echo Option 3" 
        export TMPDIR=${plexmediaserver_tmp};
        install -d -g ${plexmediaserver_group} -o ${plexmediaserver_user} "${plexmediaserver_tmp}";
    fi
}

plex_stop_precmd()
{
    if [ -r ${pidfile} ]; then
        export _PLEXPID=$(check_pidfile ${pidfile} ${procname})
    fi
}

plex_stop_postcmd()
{
    _PLEX_CHILDREN=$(pgrep -g ${_PLEXPID})
    echo "Cleaning up leftover child processes."
    kill $sig_stop ${_PLEX_CHILDREN}
    wait_for_pids ${_PLEX_CHILDREN}
}

run_rc_command "$1"
```

Comment: do you have `plexmediaserver_enable="YES"` in `/etc/rc.conf` ?

Comment: Yes. It's already in there.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this issue because I manually replaced the plex files in `/usr/local/share/plexmediaserver` with the ones from the downloaded .tar.bz2 and the `rc.d` script wouldn't work anymore.
I'm still not sure why, but this is what I did to fix it.
I added this below `stop_postcmd`:

```
start_cmd=plex_start
```

Then I added the `plex_start()` function

```
plex_start()
{
      cd ${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_HOME}
      ./start
}
```

Probably could be done better but this was a quick and dirty fix for me.  I'm not sure if the script kills the process but I just tried restarting the Jail and it started up automatically so that's all I care about.